# SQL - When to use @Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, raiserror

I found this piece of code online:

```
...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 DECLARE
   @ErMessage NVARCHAR(2048),
   @ErSeverity INT,
   @ErState INT
 
 SELECT
   @ErMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
   @ErSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
   @ErState = ERROR_STATE()
 
 **RAISERROR (@ErMessage,
             @ErSeverity,
             @ErState )**
END CATCH
```

My Questions is: In the CATCH block, why did the author have to declare the arguments with @ErMessage, @ErServerity, @ErState and not just input:

RAISERROR (ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERRORSTATE())

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh - SQL Server i believe. This is where I found the code: https://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/

Comment: You should just use `THROW` anyway to rethrow the error - the `RAISERROR` code as written can fail if the original error was a high severity error and has other disadvantages that are likely mentioned in the article you link

Comment: In fact, you probably shouldn't bother with `TRY` `CATCH` anyway, unless you actually plan on handling the error. As it stands, you are going to just mess up client side error handling, because sometimes multiple messages are returned, also you lose the error number. `THROW` should also be used only like this `THROW;` so you rethrow the original exception

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, this has been [discussed here (msdn)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12236a2c-418d-46f6-ae2b-2a644e892f94/using-expression-for-a-stored-procedure-argument-syntax-error?forum=transactsql) (a bit older).

In short: Microsoft just hasn't implemented full evaluation of expressions as parameters.
Also, allowing statements without semicolons and some context-dependent keywords would make it more complicated.